# Moving monthly average by day without LAG function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following general table structure and I need to figure out a 3/6/9/12 month average for each day without utilizing the lag function.

```
Date       | Amount    
01-01-2018 | 100   
02-01-2018 | 700   
03-01-2018 | 300   
etc
```

For example, a 3 month average on Jul 15, 2018, would look up values on Jun 15, May 15, and Apr 15. A 3 month average on May 31st would need to lookup Apr 30, Mar 31, and Feb 28.

LAG works very well, but with a variable offset the performance is absolutely dreadful. With a consistent offset of say 1, it works very fast. I have an index on date.

Below was my current code to find a 3 month average every day using LAG, but again due to poor performance I need an alternative which I'm struggling to find. I tried pre-calculating the offset value daily and referencing that column value in the function but that didn't help performance.

```
(Lag([Amount], DateDiff(d, DateAdd(month, -1, [Date]), [Date]), NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) +
 Lag([Amount], DateDiff(d, DateAdd(month, -2, [Date]), [Date]), NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) +
 Lag([Amount], DateDiff(d, DateAdd(month, -3, [Date]), [Date]), NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC)
) / 3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could *try* a join:

```
select (t1.amount + t2.amount + t3.amount) / 3
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.date = dateadd(month, -1, t1.date) left join
     t t3
     on t3.date = dateadd(month, -2, t1.date)
```